# Need help with wiring a motion wall switch

Tags: wiring

I brought two motion wall light switch to replaced two regular on and off switches. I install the one upstairs first and it seems to work ok. I them installed the 2nd one downstairs, but I'm not getting anything on the downstairs switch. I hooked the up the same way as the one upstairs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. We'd need photos to make much sense of it.  Have you tried swapping the hot and switched-hot leads?  It matters on most of those.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question?

Comment: Is this a 3-way setup?